# Custom view position after animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

i have create a custom view (circle) consisting of 20 arcs of equal degrees in the onDraw() method.

[image]

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++) {
            if (i >= 0) {
                temp += (int) value_degree[i];
                paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
                canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint); 
          //then i attach text and collor to each arc....

            }
```

I did attach animation on the view so the circle can spin on its center and the position of the arcs can  change after sniping

```
 public void createAnimation(float vel) {
        anim = new RotateAnimation(animStart, vel, centerXX, centerYY);

        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setFillEnabled(true);   
        anim.setDuration(1000L);

        startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Is there any way i can know the position of a an arc on the screen after the animation finishes?For example the degrees in respect to the screen, the top red arc is at 72 t 90 degrees.

Comment: Well, you've set the rotation velocity, you know the amount of time you are rotating at that velocity, and you know the original positions of the arcs, as YOU ARE the one that placed them.  Seems to me that with those three things, you can figure out the positions of all arcs.  At least from your question, this should be true unless you have another idea in mind.

Comment: velocity comes directly as pixels per second from onFling method.I am not sure how to convert it so i can find the total rotation